# How to overlay table elements after changing their size

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I'm working on a website that would allows users to post advertisements - they are displayed as a table of post-it notes on the board. I'm generating them using JSP's c:forEach tag (advertisements are stored in XML file) - every advertisement is a cell of a table. I added a functionality that allows to see full content of the advertisement after clicking on it (I also change the size of advertisement's div). And here is my question - I would like the bigger versions of advertisements (after clicking on them) to overlap with other advertisements located nearby, instead of moving them along. Is something like that even possible?

PS: Sorry for my English, I hope you understand what I want to achieve.

---

Or maybe I will change my question - I would like to display full version of the advertisement in new window, but I don't know how to forward a whole bean to the JSP page (the one which I want to open in new window). I will be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can have a different css class for an expanded view, then put a div within the table cell, and when the advertisement is displayed, you can set "overflow: visible" for the td to see its contents in full size.

[See this link for overflow property](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)